# Jackson FasterXML doesn't fail for invalid XML

Tags: java, xml, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

Below code doesn't throw error, maybe it couldn't parse, but returns `appConfig` fields as `null`. I've tried JAXB, unlike that JAXB throws error. I need that my code couldn't parse when xml is invalid. How can I do that?

Pojo:

```java
import lombok.Data;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@Data
@JsonRootName("app-config")
public class Config {
    private String type;
    private String body;
}
```

XML(config-invalid.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invalid></invalid>
```

Deserialize XML:

```java
...
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE);
xmlMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
Config appConfig = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("config-invalid.xml"), Config.class);
...
```

It throws only xml like below:
XML(config-invalid.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<app-config>
    <invalid></invalid>
</app-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below line otherwise Jackson XML ignores the root element.

```
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

I provide below the code snippet, you can check.

```
........
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
xmlMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE);
xmlMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
........
```